Maximizing an expression which involved $p$ which probability of a vaccine causing side effect.
The Question
A particular Covid-19 vaccine produces a side effect (fever) with probability $p \in[0,1]$. A clinic vaccinates 500 people each day and records the number of people having side effects on 5 randomly chosen days.
(i) What is the probability that the number of people who developed side effects on the 5 observed days are $10,15,0,20,25 ?$
(ii) Find the value of $p$ that maximizes the probability obtained in part (i).
(iii) Based on the value of $p$ obtained in part (ii), what is the expected number of people who will develop side effects on each day?
My Attempt
1.) $P(\text{10 side effects on Day 1}) = {500 \choose 10}p^{10}(1-p)^{490}$
Since, 10 people are already recorded to have side effects, on day two the number of people being checked is 490.
$P(\text{15 side effects on Day 2}) = {490 \choose 15}p^{15}(1-p)^{475}$
$P(\text{0 side effects on Day 3}) = p^{0}(1-p)^{475}$
$P(\text{20 side effects on Day 4}) = {475 \choose 20}p^{20}(1-p)^{455}$
$P(\text{25 side effects on Day 5}) = {455 \choose 25 }p^{25}(1-p)^{430}$
So the total Probability that the number of people who developed side effects on the 5 observed days are $10,15,0,20,25 = K \cdot p^{70}(1-p)^{2325}$ where $K$ is some positive integer.
2.)
After differentiating, the above expression is $0$ when $p = \frac{70}{2395}$. So, the above expression is maximized at $p = \frac{70}{2395}$
3.) I am confused about the expectation part, please help. Do I have to fix a particular day and calculate expectation on that day? But won't that depend on how many patients have been recorded earlier? Kindly help with the third part.

If for each day $500$ different people is tested

Probabilities for each day are:
$$\begin{pmatrix}500 \\ 10\end{pmatrix} p^{15} (1-p)^{490}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}500 \\ 15\end{pmatrix} p^{10} (1-p)^{485}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}500 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} p^{0} (1-p)^{500}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}500 \\ 20\end{pmatrix} p^{20} (1-p)^{480}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}500 \\ 25\end{pmatrix} p^{25} (1-p)^{475}$$

Since the chosen days are independent we multiply the probabilities to get the final result.

Previous expression is differentiated and set to $0$ to get the optimal value, which is
$$p = \frac{70}{2437}$$

The expected value for each day is equal since they have the same distribution, namely, Binomial(500, p):
$$np = 500 \cdot \frac{70}{2437} \approx 14.36$$


